# Adding an error to the view from a function in the model

Tags: php, yii

I am codeing the functionality for the user to change the password inside the Yii framework.The view requires the user to enter his current password and his new password twice.To compare the old passwords together i added the following method in the model.

```
public function findPassword(){
        $user = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
        if(password_verify($user->password,$this->oldPassword) !== true){
            $this->addError($this->attribute,'Old password is incorrect');
        }
    }
```

and i have the following rule inside the model.

```
array('old_password', 'findPassword', 'on' => 'changePwd'),
```

When i do this and go on the form and try to change the password i am getting the following [error](http://awesomescreenshot.com/09c3j21601)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function findPassword(){
    $user = Users::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    if(password_verify($user->password,$this->oldPassword) !== true){
        $this->addError('old_password','Old password is incorrect');
    }
}
```

Example: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/

Comment: it gives me the following error Undefined variable: attribute which makes sense since there is no $attribute inside the function.Is it good practice I used the setFlash function inside the model or should i just use those kind of errors inside of the controller.

Comment: Ok, i Edit my answer. SetFlash in controller.